# Using $.Deferred, promises, and $.ajax to build a dependency response map

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dependencies, promise

I have an array of JS resources I need to request. The order must be maintained, and the responses must be in the order that I request them in. The following requests each one in sequence, but I cannot capture the .done() promise callback on the entire request.

I call the getScripts method from my object:

```
var depArray = ['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js'];
getScripts(depArray, global_config.jspath + "/");
```

This iterates over the array within a $.Deferred() a nested $.when promise...

```
    getScripts : function(arr, path) {
        var depMap = [];
        $.Deferred(
            $.map(arr, function(src) {
                $.when(
                    $.ajax({
                            url: (path || "") + src + ".js",
                            success: function (data) {
                                depMap.push(data);
                                //return data;
                            }
                        }
                    )
                ).then(function() {
                    console.log("request complete...", (path || "") + src + ".js");
                    return true;
                });
            })
        ).done(
            function() { alert('completely done!!!!'); }
        );
    },
```

The alert('completely done!!!!') is fired immediately, not waiting for the ajax calls to execute and finish. I need to return the depMap array from the method, so I have a map of all the responses, in order, from the call.

The response would be:

```
['contents from file1.js', 'contents from file2.js', 'contents from file3.js']
```

But I never have a depMap to hand off at the end. Promises are still a bit baffling to me. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Uh, `$.Deferred` doesn't take an array of `undefined`s as its argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, some cleanup is needed. First of all, remove `$.Deferred` - it's not needed since you already have `$.when` promise. Then you need to construct array of promises and pass it into `$.when`.

Finally, it can look like this:

```
getScripts: function(arr, path) {
    // map each promise to its resource and aggregate
    return $.when.apply(null, arr.map(function(src) {
        return $.ajax({url: (path || "") + src + ".js"});
    })).then(function(){
        return [].map.call(arguments, function(x){ return x[0]; }) // just the data
    });
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/DvBj9PcaTQzskCRIUAHZ?p=preview

Comment: There's no guarantee the ajax calls will return in the order they were invoked, so the code in your answer cannot guarantee the order of the items in the `depMap` array.

Comment: Yes, good catch. I initially wanted to post answer with real promises, that's why I wrote it like this, didn't fix it for jQuery.

Comment: "real promises"? Are you referring to promises from a different library?

Comment: I mean real Promises/A+ complaint implementations.

Comment: I want to enforce that the ajax calls are done in sequence with the use of promises. One cannot finish before the other. I understand that you cannot guarantee the order of arrays, but given a map.. the ajax/getScript calls need to be requested in order.

Comment: @Bergi I'm aware of it, but in this case I was avoiding poor jQuery promise implementation so I had to use it.

Comment: @dfsq: I see that you only wanted a single result parameter, but `return $.ajax(…).then(function(data) { return data; })` would have sufficed for that. And even if you were aware of it, you still forgot to propagate errors.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum Thanks for the edit! This is strange, I surely tried proper code before my dirty jQuery deferred hack. Must have missed something little then.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.ajax()` function returns a `jqXHR` object, which is a Promise. The `$.when()` function says it takes one or more Deferred objects, but it appears to require that they only be Promises, not full Deferred objects. Therefore, you do not need to use `$.Deferred()` to create Deferred objects for each ajax request. You can just use the objects returned by `$.ajax()`. You can use `$.map()` to create an array of the promises, in the order the ajax calls were made.

Ultimately though, your `getScripts()` function cannot return the `depMap` array because it is asynchronous. Instead, it could be written to return a Promise, as shown below.

```
getScripts: function(arr, path) {
    return $.when.apply($, $.map(arr, function(src) {
        return $.ajax({ url: (path || '') + src + '.js' });
    })).then(function() {
        return (arr.length > 1)
            ? $.map(arguments, function(a) { return a[0]; })
            : [arguments[0]];
    });
},
```

For information on how the array returned from the `$.when(...).then()` function is constructed from the arguments to its callback function, see [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22416857/859640). (The same info for `.done()` applies to `.then()`.)

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c0sr295L/)