# Fill array by multiple AJAX requests, then pass array to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

*(My solution below)*

I have several HTML elements with class `.canvas-background` of which information is stored in the database. I want to get the information of each element and process it via JavaScript. But somehow I can't pass the response of the AJAX request to another function. Here is what I've tried:

```
function initTabs() {
    var tabs = loadTabInformation();
    console.log(tabs); // (1)
    // do something else
}

function loadTabInformation() {
    var requests = new Array();
    var tabs = new Object();
    var counter = 0;
    $(".canvas-background").each(function () {
        var tabNumber = $(this).data("tab-number");
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../db/GetTabInformation.ashx',
            data: String(tabNumber),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'text/plain; charset-utf-8'
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            tabs[counter++] = response;
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("request error in loadTabInformation()");
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        });
        requests.push(request);
    });
    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {
        console.log(tabs); // (2)
        return tabs;
    });
}
```

At `(1)` I get `undefined`, but at `(2)` everything seems to be alright.

**THE SOLUTION:**

Thanks to the answer and the link in the comment @Kim Hoang provided I got this working. The clue seemed to put the `done()` function in the calling function, that is `initTabs()` in my case. Another thing I got wrong was to try to do the logic that should be executed *after* the AJAX requests had finished outside the done callback function. They must be inside (makes sense, if you think about it). And a lot of conosle output helped, to see what function returns what kind of object.

```
function initTabs() {
    var tabInfoRequest = loadTabInfo();
    tabInfoRequest[0].done(function() {
        var results = (tabInfoRequest[1].length > 1) ? $.map(arguments, function(a) { return a[0]; }) : [arguments[0]];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            // do something with results[i]
        }
    });
}

function loadTabInfo() {
    var tabNumbers = new Array();
    $(".canvas-background").each(function () {
        tabNumbers.push($(this).data("tab-number"));
    });
    var requests = $.map(tabNumbers, function (current) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../db/GetTabInformation.ashx',
            data: String(current),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'text/plain; charset-utf-8'
        });
    });
    var resultObject = new Object();
    resultObject[0] = $.when.apply($, requests);
    resultObject[1] = requests;
    return resultObject;
}
```

Note: I only did the `resultObject`-thing because I needed the array `requests` in the `initTabs()` function.

Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not return anything in `loadTabInformation`, so of course you will get `undefined`. You should do it like this:

```
function loadTabInformation() {
    ...
    return $.when.apply($, requests);
}

function initTabs() {
    loadTabInformation().done(function (tabs) {
        console.log(tabs); // (1)
        // do something else
    });    
}
```

Comment: OK, this puts me closer to the solution. But the `tabs` parameter of the function inside `done` only contains the first response. I tried adding `tabs2` and `tabs3` as parameters, and I got all three responses. Is it possible to do this for a variable number of responses?

Comment: @elementzero23, you may want to look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416073/when-and-done-using-an-array-with-done for the way to handle array of promise in $.when. Basically you need to use the arguments object, each argument will contain [data, statusText, jqXHR]